# How to rotate mask of image pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Hi i have trouble with rotating mask of object that is rotating mask is still in the same position as original image. The point is to move mask form collision in race track.

```
    def __init__(self, x, y , height , width):
        self.x = x - width / 2
        self.y = y - height / 2
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.car_img = pygame.image.load('img/auticko.png').convert_alpha()
        self.car_rect = self.car_img.get_rect()
        self.car_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.car_img)
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((height, width),pygame.SRCALPHA)

        self.surface.blit(self.car_img, (0, 0))
        self.angle = 0
        self.speed = 2
    def draw(self,screen):  # 3
        self.car_rect.topleft = (int(self.x), int(self.y))
        rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(self.surface, self.angle)
        #rotated.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
        surface_rect = self.surface.get_rect(topleft=self.car_rect.topleft)
        new_rect = rotated.get_rect(center=surface_rect.center)
        screen.blit(rotated, new_rect.topleft)
```

i was trying to make new mask from surface but its not working
as you can see on image while turning cars got stacked corner when they should not be
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epSmu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rotate the mask, but you can create a new mask after rotating the image:

```py
rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(self.surface, self.angle)
self.car_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(rotated)
```

Comment: i was trying that already and it didnt help so the bug will be somewhere else

Comment: offset = (int(cars.cars[counter].x), int(cars.cars[counter].y))
track.track_mask.overlap(cars.cars[counter].car_mask, offset)

Comment: im using that for collision map is draw at 0,0

Comment: cars.cars[counter].y -= cars.cars[counter].speed * math.sin(math.radians(cars.cars[counter].angle)) # 8 cars.cars[counter].x += cars.cars[counter].speed * math.cos(math.radians(-cars.cars[counter].angle)) # 8 im or not bcs im changing x and y